# Can a subset not belonging to $\mathbb R^n$ still be contained in a subspace different than $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So basically I have the following subset $$W = \{(x,x,xy,y,y)\} : x,y \in \mathbb R\}$$ that, after checking if it is closed to addition and multiplication I realize it is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^5$ and I am asked if:

a) $W$ is contained in a proper subspace $U$ such that $W \subseteq U \neq \mathbb R^5$

b) $W$ contains a sub space $V$ that is not null ($0\neq V\subseteq W$)

I am having troubles proving those 2 statements most of all because I believe to be missing some theorem or property. How can this subset $W$, that is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^5$, be contained in a subspace $U$? For $U$ to be a subspace shouldn't it hold the properties of addition and multiplication? And if so, how does $W$ can be contained in this subspace if $W$ does not hold those properties? Also, I have no clue on how to find a subspace $U$ such that $W \subseteq U \neq \mathbb R^5$.

Comment: For example:  the segment $(0,0)+\lambda(1,1)$ , $\lambda \in [0,1]$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ , but it's contained in the line $(x,x)$ which is a subspace. Similary, the halfplane $(x,y)$ with $x<1$ and $y$ arbitrary is not a subspace but includes the $y$ axis, which is a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

$W$ is not a subspace itself because there are vectors $\vec a \in W$ and $\vec b \in W$ such that $\vec a + \vec b \notin W$. But it doesn't mean $W$ can't be a subset of a proper subspace: for example, if you take a segment containing origin on plane - it's not a subspace, but it is a subset of line containing this segment, and this line is a proper subspace.

Can you write some equation of form $a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + a_3 x_3 + a_4 x_4 + a_5 x_5 = 0$ with not all $a_i = 0$, such that any point from $W$ satisfies this equation? (hint: you can even take $a_3 = a_4 = a_5 = 0$) Set of all solutions of this equation will then be a proper subspace containing $W$.

The second part is similar - all we need is several equations of such form so that every point that satisfies them is in $W$. For example, we can take $x_1 = x_2$, $x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = 0$.